# LabVIEW: How to exchange lots of variables between loops?

Tags: arrays, loops, labview

I have two loops:

1. One loop gets data from a device and processes it. Scales received variables, calculates extra data.
2. Second loop visualizes the data and stores it.

There are lots of different variables that need to passed between those two loops - about 50 variables. I need the second loop to have access only to the newest values of the data. It needs to be able to read those variables any time they are needed to be visualized.

What is the best way to share such vector between two loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways of sharing data.
The fastest and simplest is a local variable, however that is rather uncontrolled, and you need to make sure to write them at **one** place (plus you need an indicator).
One of the most advanced options is creating a class for your data, and use an instance (if you create a by-ref class, otherwise it won't matter), and create a public 'GET' method.

In between you have sevaral other options:

- queues
- semaphores
- property nodes
- global variables
- shared variables
- notifiers
- events
- TCP-IP

In short there is no best way, it all depends on your skills and application.

Comment: I ended up with the events way. Any producer loop generated events containing custom data with a bundled enum (containing event type from a predefined list) and a variant with the event data. Consumer loops catch any events throughout the application, read the enum and then cast the variant to a proper data type, depending on the enum value. It works like a charm with ~100 different enum/data types with very high sampling rates. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're considering loops within the SAME application, there ARE good and bad ideas, though:

```
queues (OK, has most features)
notifiers (OK)
events (OK)
FGVs (OK, but keep an eye on massively parallel access hindering exec)

semaphores (that's not data comms)
property nodes (very inefficient, prone to race cond.)
global variables (prone to race cond.)
shared variables (badly implemented by NI, prone to race cond.)
TCP-IP (slow, awkward, affected by firewall config)
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way to do this is to write each value to an indicator in the producer loop - these indicators can be hidden offscreen, or in a page of a tab control, if you don't want to see them - and read a local variable of each one in the consumer loop. However if you have 50 different values it may become hard to maintain this code if you need to change or extend it.

As Ton says there are many different options but my suggestion would be:

- Create a cluster control, with named elements, containing all your data
- Save this cluster as a typedef
- Create a notifier using this cluster as the data type
- Bundle the data into the cluster (by name) and write this to the notifier in the producer loop
- Read the cluster from the notifier in the consumer loop, unbundle it by name and do what you want with each element.

Using a cluster means you can easily pass it to different subVIs to process different elements if you like, and saving as a typedef means you can add, rename or alter the elements and your code will update to match. In your consumer loop you can use the timeout setting of the notifier read to control the loop timing, if you want. You can also use the notifier to tell the loops when to exit, by force-destroying it and trapping the error.

Comment: I agree a Notifier is the correct pattern for displaying "only to the newest values of the data".

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Use a display loop with SEQ (Single Element Queue)
2. Use a event structure with User Event. (Do not put two event structures in same loop!! Use another)

Use an enum with case structure and variant to cast the data to expected type.

(Notifier isn't reliable to stream data, because is a **lossy** scheme. Leave this only to trigger small actions)

Comment: The questioner says "I need the second loop to have access only to the newest values of the data." That's exactly what a notifier does. If they wanted to capture and log every value that's been acquired, then a queue would be more suitable, but for this use case the notifier is ideal.

Comment: Perhaps our friend doesn't like the idea of losing data during display/logging process. The producer loop should be more slower than the consumer to give a "chance" to not losing values...

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that the second loop 'stores' the data as well as visualising it, though that doesn't fit with the comment that 'only the newest' values are needed. Display and logging are typically two different processes that should be handled in separate loops - so e.g. the logging loop can stop and wait for disk or network I/O without freezing the display. Use a notifier for display and a queue for logging.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your variables can be bundled together in a single cluster to send at once, then you should use a single element queue. If your requirements change later such that the transmission cannot be lossy, then it's a matter of changing the input to the Obtain Queue VI (with a notifier you'd have to swap out all of the VIs). Setting up individual indicators and local variables would be pretty darn tedious. Also, not good style.

Answer (score 0):

If the loops are inside of the same VI then:

The simplest solution would be local variables.
Little bit better to use shared variables.
Better is to use functional global variables (FGVs)
The best solution would be using SEQ (Single Element Queue).

Anyway for better understanding please go trough [this paper](ftp://ftp.ni.com/pub/branches/uk/devdays_2011/Best_Practices_for_Inter_Process_and_Inter_Target_Data_Communication_Using_LabVIEW.pdf).